# erase gets const_iterator but is called with iterator (non-const)

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, std, stdvector

In C++11 `std::vector::erase` gets as first argument `const_iterator` (older one was with iterator):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/

But as you can see in the example it uses with not `cbegin`. Instead it uses with `begin`. Is there an implicit conversion between `const_iterator` and `iterator`?

Comment: There is an implicit conversion from `iterator` to `const_iterator`, but not generally the other way obviously.

Comment: Moral of the story: Use reliable reference documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `iterator` of std containers is (and must be) convertible to `const_iterator`.

From the standard, [$23.2.1/4 General container requirements [container.requirements.general] Table 100 — Container requirements](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.general#tab:containers.container.requirements):

(Emphasis mine)

> X::iterator
>
> any iterator category that meets the forward iterator requirements.
>   **convertible to X::const_iterator**.

Answer (score 3):

The requirement on `containers` is that `iterator` type must be implcitly convertible to `const_iterator`.

See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container

So, something like below will work:

```
std::vector<int> v;
.....
std::vector<int>::const_iterator cit = v.begin();
```